# Create an Alphanumeric List + Sort Alphanumeric List

Tags: sorting, ironpython

I have 2 questions:

1. Is there a more efficient way to create an alphanumeric list like the following?

   def CreateList():
   numb=range(1,21)
   StringList=[]
   for i in numb:
   StringList.append("C"+str(i))
   return StringList

   StringList=CreateList()
   print (StringList)

['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7', 'C8', 'C9', 'C10', 'C11', 'C12', 'C13', 'C14', 'C15', 'C16', 'C17', 'C18', 'C19', 'C20']

2. If I have an alphanumeric list like the one below, what the best way to sort it?

['C1', 'C10', 'C11', 'C12', 'C13', 'C14', 'C15', 'C16', 'C17', 'C18', 'C19', 'C2', 'C20', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7', 'C8', 'C9']

Comment: Instead of creating a function, you can use list comprehension:`StringList = ["C" + str (i) for i in range (1,21)]`

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Any ideas how to sort the second list?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub TestMethod()
Dim Lne As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim aryTextFile() As String
Dim newfile() As String
Dim count As Integer

Line = "C1,C10,C11,C12,C13,C14,C15,C16,C17,C18,C19,C2,C20,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7,C8,C9"
 
aryTextFile = Split(Line, ",")
ReDim Preserve newfile(UBound(aryTextFile)) As String

count = 0
For i = 0 To UBound(aryTextFile)
    If Len(aryTextFile(i)) <= 2 Then
        newfile(count) = aryTextFile(i)
       count = count + 1
     End If
 Next i


For i = 0 To UBound(aryTextFile)
    If Len(aryTextFile(i)) = 3 Then
        newfile(count) = aryTextFile(i)
        count = count + 1
    End If
Next i

For i = 0 To UBound(aryTextFile)
    If Len(aryTextFile(i)) = 4 Then
        newfile(count) = aryTextFile(i)
        count = count + 1
    End If
Next i
 
newLine = Join(newfile, ",")
strOut = newLine
  
Debug.Print (strOut)




End Sub
```

I had something similar.  If the list is in alpha numeric order then you can load up a new array with a for loop looking for string lengths of 2 in the original sorted array and load them at the front of the new array.  Then another for loop for string lengths of 3 and so on.